ClickHouse Materialised View With Latest Set of Rows
I have a table in ClickHouse with a set of rows, each of which represent parts of events in my system, an event events like "Delete" or "Create" will be one row, an event like "Compute" will be n rows (usually 3-4).
e.g
| Job Id  | Event Type |Event Set ID |Value         |Scope   |
| --------| -----------|-------------|--------------|--------|
| 1234    | Created    | 55          | NIL          |
| 1234    | Computed   | 66          | 104.5        | 1
| 1234    | Computed   | 66          | 222          | 7
| 1234    | Computed   | 66          | 8475.5       | 3
| 1234    | Computed   | 77          | 9332.9       | 3
| 1234    | Computed   | 77          | 1023883.4    | 5


I will have many millions of these events. I would like to easily query the latest set of events for a given job id since the latest group of events by "Event Set Id" are the latest state of a given job.
I don't want to aggregate rows together by "Event Set ID" at this point since I would like to query on Scope (and many other columns) that are per row, not per job.
I was looking at a ReplacingMergeTree Materialised View but this seems to only work for one primary key.
Is there a way to have a "multi row" materialised view or similar, i.e. keep all the rows for the latest "Event Set ID" for each "Job ID".
The way I could do this right now to, for example, get the sum of values for the latest event sets:
SELECT SUM(value) FROM events WHERE event_set_id IN (SELECT MAX(event_set_id) FROM events GROUP BY job_id)

But this can be quite slow on a large table and needs to read many rows which are irrelevant since they are superseded by a new "event set"

looks like you need to add event_time field
and use in materialized view ENGINE=ReplcingMergeTree(event_time) ORDER BY (job_id, event_type)

As @Slach mentoined, you can combine multiple columns in ORDER BY in materialized view. For your case  expression ORDER BY (job_id, event_set_id) will allow you to have multiple event_set_id per job_id
